# f:attribute within ice:commandLink fails

Tags: jsf, icefaces, icefaces-1.8

I'm using `f:attribute` in the following way and for some reason I get `NPE`

```
<ice:panelSeries id="panel" value="#{userBean.disp}" var="bean">
<ice:commandLink actionListener="#{actionBean.reset}">
    <f:attribute name="myList" value="#{bean.myList}"/>
    <f:param name="myParam" value="#{bean.myString}"/>
</ice:commandLink>
.....
</ice:panelSeries>
```

Exception stacktrace:

```
com.icesoft.faces.webapp.parser.Parser parse Failed to execute JSP lifecycle.
                             java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase$AttributesMap.put(UIComponentBase.java:1655)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase$AttributesMap.put(UIComponentBase.java:1525)
at javax.faces.webapp.AttributeTag.doStartTag(AttributeTag.java:151)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.parser.Parser.executeJspLifecycle(Parser.java:204)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.parser.Parser.executeJspLifecycle(Parser.java:229)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.parser.Parser.executeJspLifecycle(Parser.java:229)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.parser.Parser.executeJspLifecycle(Parser.java:229)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.parser.Parser.executeJspLifecycle(Parser.java:229)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.parser.Parser.executeJspLifecycle(Parser.java:229)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.parser.Parser.executeJspLifecycle(Parser.java:229)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.parser.Parser.executeJspLifecycle(Parser.java:229)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.parser.Parser.executeJspLifecycle(Parser.java:229)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.parser.Parser.executeJspLifecycle(Parser.java:229)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.parser.Parser.executeJspLifecycle(Parser.java:229)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.parser.Parser.executeJspLifecycle(Parser.java:229)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.parser.Parser.executeJspLifecycle(Parser.java:229)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.parser.Parser.executeJspLifecycle(Parser.java:229)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.parser.Parser.executeJspLifecycle(Parser.java:229)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.parser.Parser.executeJspLifecycle(Parser.java:229)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.parser.Parser.executeJspLifecycle(Parser.java:229)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.parser.Parser.executeJspLifecycle(Parser.java:229)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.parser.Parser.executeJspLifecycle(Parser.java:229)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.parser.Parser.executeJspLifecycle(Parser.java:229)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:162)
at com.icesoft.faces.application.D2DViewHandler.renderResponse(D2DViewHandler.java:439)
at com.icesoft.faces.application.D2DViewHandler.renderView(D2DViewHandler.java:159)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:114)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.JsfLifecycleExecutor.apply(JsfLifecycleExecutor.java:19)
at com.icesoft.faces.context.View$2$1.respond(View.java:48)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.ServletRequestResponse.respondWith(ServletRequestResponse.java:201)
at com.icesoft.faces.context.View$2.serve(View.java:77)
at com.icesoft.faces.context.View.servePage(View.java:149)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.MultiViewServer.service(MultiViewServer.java:79)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.common.ServerProxy.service(ServerProxy.java:11)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.MainSessionBoundServlet$4.service(MainSessionBoundServlet.java:149)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.common.standard.PathDispatcherServer.service(PathDispatcherServer.java:24)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.BasicAdaptingServlet.service(BasicAdaptingServlet.java:16)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.PathDispatcher.service(PathDispatcher.java:23)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.SessionDispatcher.service(SessionDispatcher.java:60)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.PathDispatcher.service(PathDispatcher.java:23)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:148)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1663)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:939)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:354)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:564)
at com.ibm._jsp._index._jspService(_index.java:85)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:99)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1663)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:939)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:121)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:259)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:354)
at com.bnsf.mech.earl.servlet.EarlServlet.callView(EarlServlet.java:255)
at com.bnsf.mech.earl.servlet.EarlServlet.performTask(EarlServlet.java:78)
at com.bnsf.mech.earl.servlet.EarlServlet.doPost(EarlServlet.java:54)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738)
at com.bnsf.wasweb5.WasServlet.service(WasServlet.java:378)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1663)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:939)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:91)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:864)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1583)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:276)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1604)
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo! Please see corrected

Comment: Looks like some attribute there has `null` value thus giving you the Exception. Try to isolate the problem to see which variable is the culprit of your problem.

Comment: You are right, it takes null only for `f:attribute` but not for all other components like `ice:outputText` etc., any idea why?

Comment: I figured the `f:attribute` is not gonna work(I assume `f:attribute` is looked for at the time of generating the view and `bean.myList` cannot be null while for other components it can be null) So I think the only way is to go for `f:setPropertyActionListener` experts please advise if there is any other way....

Comment: What JSF version are you working with?

Comment: Well, it is a deprecated version of JSF =\. Still, AFAICS if you need this `bean.myList` to be retrieved when user selects your commandButton, you can have your managed bean in session scope or save/retrieve the list in/from HttpSession. After that, I think there's no other possibility for you to handle the list.

Comment: I finally found the answer from this


  https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014035341 , sorry for incomplete code, I modified the question now... Thanks for your time :)

Comment: And yes you are right, I used a session scoped bean and it works :)